# Why ever choose "share nothing" over "share everything"?

Tags: architecture, distributed-computing, disk

My *understanding* of a "share nothing" distributed system is that each node in the cluster has its own disk to persist to. If this is the case, I'm not sure why it would ever be beneficial to have such an architecture, because not only would you need replication/load balancing/clustering at the application level, but then you also need replication at the disk-level so that all the disk nodes in the cluster can see each other as well.

So I ask: under what circumstances is "shared nothing" a better choice to "shared everything", and are there any other choices besides these two? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the following advantages of shared-nothing distributed systems:

- Fault isolation. A fault in any single node will be contained in that node and exposed only through messages (or lack of them), allowing fault tolerant systems to be implemented. A simple example: a file system bug in a shared disk file system can potentially corrupt the entire persistent state.
- Scalability. If the disk is a shared resource, then available controller and disk bandwidth are also shared. Moreover, consistent shared state requires some form of synchronization, in which different nodes take turns to access critical data. Both of these will limit how much nodes can eventually be added to the distributed shared-disk system.